# OnCollisionEnter2D not being executed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Hey I have this script on a prefab of a projectile , that is suppose to be destroyed when collide with something. Well my problem is that when it collides with something this method is never triggered and I don't know why. I even have that debug and it never appears on it . The projectile has rigibody(kinematic) and box colider ! The thing he is suppose to collide with has colider too.

```
public class ProjectileColision : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject projectile;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    Debug.Log("executed");


    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Projectile")
    {
        Destroy(projectile,0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: And they are in Layers that are set to collide with eachother in the Layer Collision Matrix? (Project Settings-> Physics (or Physics 2D)

Comment: Yes they are :/

Comment: None of the colliders are set to "Is Trigger"?

Comment: Very strange. As others have mentioned, 2D physics and 3D physics don't interact. Are all your box colliders actually `BoxCollider2D`? You've checked the collision matrix, but did you check the 2D collision matrix? Is the object it's colliding with set to `isTrigger = false`?

Comment: My isTrigger is false in the projectile , I putted it true but still not running the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its because of `kinematic`

> A kinematic Rigidbody2D will only collide with a dynamic Rigidbody2D
>   body type. The exception to this is if Rigidbody2D.useFullKinematicContacts is set to true in which case it will collide with all other Rigidbody2D body types.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic.html

Try setting `Body Type` to `Dynamic` and see if `OnCollisionEnter` executes.

**OR**

Add a dynamic `Rigidbody2D` to the other collider

Comment: Are you sure that the tag of the other gameobject should be "Projectile"? You could try Debug.Log(col.gameObject.tag) to see what you are colliding with to verify

Comment: Yea I fixed it thank you for your help buddy rly great !

Answer (score 1):

copying the exact same code you have worked, My guess is that you are using Rigidbody instead of Rigidbody2D component on your GameObject.

Comment: screenshot the inspector to check it. or upload the project.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who reaches here and might be having a hard time debugging this problem, you need to be careful when changing your script from `OnTriggerEnter2D` to `OnCollisionEnter2D`, since one receives a `Collider2D` as an `arg`, and the other a `Collision2D`. Visual Studio doesn't give any warning and it's easy to miss.

Comment: This answer should be higher.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been more than 1 year. But I had the same problem, tested everything (spent 3 hours trying to fix it)... Then I tried to put the "void OnCollisionEnter2D" before the "Update" function... and... it worked.

My objects were colliding(bouncing on each other) but the function was not being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Much like George Mori, for me not having an Update function made it not trigger.
Adding an empty Update function made it work. It's just weird cause I'm following a tutorial and that didn't have an Update function at all.
I am using a beta version of 2019.3 though so might just be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you wrote the OnCollisionEnter2D function in void update, modify it and write outside void update, your problem will be solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).